# Combine pandas DataFrames by single column in axis 0

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to combine several pandas `DataFrames` such as these: (All inputs have a first column `P` plus a uniquely named second column.)

```
df_b3 = pd.DataFrame({'P':  ['l1','l3'],
                      'b3': ['+','+']},
                      index=[0,1])
df_ka = pd.DataFrame({'P':  ['l1','l2','l3'],
                      'ka': ['+','+','+']},
                      index=[0,1,2])
df_kb = pd.DataFrame({'P':  ['l2','l3'],
                      'kb': ['+','+']},
                      index=[0,1])
```

The output should be like this: (It should have as many columns as there are inputs, plus one column for `P`, and there should be only one row for each value in a column `P` in any input.)

```
       P   b3   ka   kb
0  l1    +    +  NaN
1  l2  NaN    +    +
2  l3    +    +    +
```

A simple `pd.concat([df_b3, df_ka, df_kb])` gives me too many rows and `NaN`s:

```
       P   b3   ka   kb
0  l1    +  NaN  NaN
0  l1  NaN    +  NaN
1  l2  NaN    +  NaN
0  l2  NaN  NaN    +
1  l3    +  NaN  NaN
2  l3  NaN    +  NaN
1  l3  NaN  NaN    +
```

How can this best be achieved with pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for each `DataFrame` for align by `P` column in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = [df_b3, df_ka, df_kb]
dfs1 = [x.set_index('P') for x in dfs]
#same as
#dfs1 = [df_b3.set_index('P'), df_ka.set_index('P'), df_kb.set_index('P')]
df = pd.concat(dfs1, axis=1).rename_axis('P').reset_index()
print (df)
    P   b3 ka   kb
0  l1    +  +  NaN
1  l2  NaN  +    +
2  l3    +  +    +
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [use join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
df_b3.join(df_ka, on='P')
```

Don't forget to choose the other options like "inner", "outer"... etc.